# Why is there no way to follow a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I frequently see questions that to which I do not know the answer but that I would like to know how to answer. On many websites there is a follow button next to where the "share", "edit", and "flag" buttons appear. There are other ways of doing this, as I am sure others will point out, but I think this button would see a lot of use.

edit - here is an example of a professional forum having such a button: https://www.biostars.org

edit 2 - as other users have indicated the ability to favorite a question is substantively different than the ability to follow a question.

Comment: If your question is substantively different from the indicated duplicate you'll need to edit to clarify what you're asking that's not covered by that question.